# how to stop a JQuery UI Draggable element scroll when using animate to scroll to an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am building a web page that has a number of elements that can be dragged into position.

The overall page is very wide and very tall and is split into horizontal "bands".

To aid navigation between bands I have a number of "hotspots" at fixed position top LHS of the browser window. When the user drags an element onto one of the hotspots the "over" event is fired and in code I animate a move to an anchor tag far down the page.

This works almost perfectly with one glitch that makes it unusable.

The draggable element scrolls with the browser and will not reapear until I nudge the cursor at which point the new position of the draggable in relation to the browser is recalculated.

I am using refreshPositions which doesn't address this problem and even using the mouse co-ordinates captured in the drag event do not seem to take effect.

Does anyone know if there is some way to call the refreshPositions in my code at the end of the "over" event?

I have been researching here for the last two days ... I can't find an answer that comes even close.

thanks

jON

Comment: It will be much more helpful if you post a piece of working code somewhere so we can help you fix it. Just my 2 cents

Comment: yes, fair point, its just that its a huge amount of code to package together in a small project as are those that I have see with here before. I will try to put together the salient parts into a test project. thanks for the reply. jON